# Custom WHMCS order template from scratch; nothign showing up

Tags: whmcs

I'm creating a custom WHHMCS order template from scratch. I've created a folder `neworderform` and put it in `/whmcs/templates/orderforms`. I put a file `cart.php` in it, and it shows up as a new theme under General Settings > Ordering, but when I go to `http://example.com/cart.php?carttpl=neworderform`, I just get a blank page and don't see the content of my file.

Is there some minimal amount of template I need in order to make it work? Right now it's basically a "hello world" file.

Answer (score 0):

I would duplicate an existing order form like "web20cart", and empty their files' content. And for your information template files uses tpl not php.